# Should the tags [history] and [music-history] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that we have a [history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag and [music-history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-history) tag. Should we keep them separate, or should we make one a synonym of the other?

Comment: (Note that I have [suggested an edit](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/80) a few hours ago, so when it gets approved, no question will have the [tag:music-history] tag anymore … for the moment.)

Answer (score 8):

I'd say we make [music-history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-history) a synonym of [history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) since this site is about music at it's core it's implied that most history questions will in some way be related to music.

Comment: If thy weren't related to music, they'd be off-topic anyway, so +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

***Caveat*** - this answer is about possible theoretical usage of [history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, NOT about any questions that may or may not be currently covered by it today.

In my opinion, [history](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is a valid separate tag for very specific usage - that is, **questions about music as it applies to/affects overall history** (as opposed to history of music itself).

Example: questions like "`effect of XYZ songs on morale of troops in WWII`".

Litmus test is that usually, such questions might be on-topic on History.SE, but would be likely a better fit here, either because there are likely to be more topic experts on this site; or because they are insufficiently academically rigorous for History.SE's academic taste.